Proving Identity Property for Cardinal Multiplication
I think what I have done is right but I am overthinking this problem.
Let $B=\{0\}$ such that $|B|=1$. Let $A$ be a set with $n$ elements. Give a bijection from $A$ to $A\times B$ and explain why it proves $D*1=D$ where $*$ is cardinal multiplication.
This is my attempt:
Let $A=\{a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots,a_n\}$
$A\times B=\{(a_1,0),(a_2,0),(a_3,0),\dots,(a_n,0)\}$
We can see there exists a bijective function $A\to A\times B$. Namely, $\forall_{a\in A}\; a_n\mapsto (a_n,0)$
This proves the identity property for cardinal multiplication because this bijection will exist regardless of the cardinality of $D$. It can be generalized to $\forall_{a\in A}\; a_n\mapsto (a_n,B)$ where $|B|=1$.
I should mention that this is for an Intro to Proofs course. I am sorry if this question seems redundant, I am new to this kind of mathematical thinking. I don't quite understand the "give a bijection" part because we've only talked about bijections with diagrams of 2 domains, connected with lines. I don't know if my mapping is an acceptable way of providing a bijection.
I appreciate any feedback on my attempt.
